# Trouble converting Tensor to NumPy using TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I try to convert the variable type to `Tensor("strided_slice_1:0", shape=(24, 24, 3), dtype=float32)` to a NumPy matrix.

```
image=images_train[1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    array1 = sess.run(image)
```

But the program is not executed after this.

Answer (score 1):

[Eager Execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) is enabled by default in TF 2.0, so you need to call `.numpy()` on the Tensor object.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(tf.__version__)

#tf.executing_eagerly()

def tensor_to_array(array_value):
    return array_value.numpy()

a = tf.constant([5.0,6.0,7.0])
b = tf.constant([6.0,8.0,9.0])
c = a * b
print(c)
print(tensor_to_array(c))
print(type(tensor_to_array(c)))
```

Output:

```
2.2.0
tf.Tensor([30. 48. 63.], shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
[30. 48. 63.]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

If Eager Execution is disabled, you can build a graph and then run it through `tf.compat.v1.Session` in `TF 2.x` and `tf.Session` in `TF 1.x`

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  a = tf.constant([5.0,6.0,7.0])
  b = tf.constant([6.0,8.0,9.0])
  c = a * b
  print(c)
  print(sess.run(c))
  print(type(sess.run(c)))
```

Output:

```
1.15.2
Tensor("mul_1:0", shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
[30. 48. 63.]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```